# How to use custom delegates in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, delegates

I need to know about the usage of delegate methods in Objective-C. Can anyone point me to the correct source?

Comment: Hi Syam, just to clarify are you coming from .NET and asking how to implement delegates (object-oriented function calls) in Objective-C?  Or are you asking how to implement Objective-C helper classes (also called delegates)?

Answer (score 129):

You will want to declare a delegate protocol for your class. An example of a delegate protocol and interface for class `Foo` might look like this:

```
@class Foo;
@protocol FooDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (BOOL)foo:(Foo *)foo willDoSomethingAnimated:(BOOL)flag;
- (void)foo:(Foo *)foo didDoSomethingAnimated:(BOOL)flag;
@end

@interface Foo : NSObject {
     NSString *bar;
     id <FooDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *bar;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <FooDelegate> delegate;

- (void)someAction;

@end
```

Don't forget to synthesize your properties in the `@implementation`.

What this code did was declare a protocol called FooDelegate; a class that conforms to this protocol would be declared like `@interface SomeClass : SuperClass <FooDelegate> {}`. Because this class conforms to the protocol `FooDelegate`, it now gets to implement the methods under `FooDelegate` (to require that these be implemented, use `@required` instead of `@optional`). The last step is for a `Foo` object to be instantiated in the class that conforms to `FooDelegate`, and for this `Foo` object to have its delegate property set:

```
Foo *obj = [[Foo alloc] init];
[obj setDelegate:self];
```

Now, your class is prepared to receive messages from `Foo` objects that have their delegates set correctly.

Comment: What is the difference between using id<FooDelegate> delegate and NSObject<FooDelegate> *delegate ?

Comment: The difference is that the latter expects `delegate` to be an instance of `NSObject` or a subclass thereof. The former only expects some kind of Objective-C object (it could be a proxy, or, God forbid, some other root object).

Comment: Thank you! I just thought that 
@protocol FooDelegate <NSObject> would imply delegate being a subclass of NSObject.

Comment: @Filipe Ah, yes, that is a bit confusing. In fact, the bracketed bit of `@protocol Blah <NSObject>` is saying that the *protocol* `<Blah>` inherits from the *protocol* `<NSObject>`. A key point to get is that there is a class `NSObject` as well as a protocol `<NSObject>`.

Comment: That made perfect sense, thanks Jonathan! Though I've noticed that if I use id instead of NSObject (for delegate type) I can't use performSelectorOnMainThread which is useful for delegates.

Answer (score 7):

Delegates are very useful to control transfer within the array of view controllers in app manually. Using delegates you can manage the control flow very well.

here is small example of own delegates....

1. Create a protocol class.... (.h only)

**SampleDelegate.h**

```
#import
@protocol SampleDelegate
@optional

#pragma Home Delegate

-(NSString *)getViewName;

@end
```

2. Import above protocol class in the class whom you want to make delegate of another class. Here in my ex. I m using AppDelegate to make delegate of The HomeViewController's Object.

also add above DelegateName in Delegate Reference < >

**ownDelegateAppDelegate.h**

```
#import "SampleDelegate.h"

@interface ownDelegateAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, SampleDelegate>
{


}
```

**ownDelegateAppDelegate.m**

```
//setDelegate of the HomeViewController's object as
[homeViewControllerObject setDelegate:self];

//add this delegate method definition
-(NSString *)getViewName
{
    return @"Delegate Called";
}
```

**HomeViewController.h**

```
#import
#import "SampleDelegate.h"

@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController 
{

    id<SampleDelegate>delegate;
}

@property(readwrite , assign) id<SampleDelegate>delegate;

@end
```

**HomeViewController.h**

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    UILabel *lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    lblTitle.text = [delegate getViewName];
    lblTitle.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    [self.view addSubview:lblTitle];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

To start, you can take a look at what Apple has to say about delegate methods.  The documentation provides some well written information about what delegation is all about, and explains both how to use AppKit classes that define and support a delegate and how to code delegate support into one of your own objects.

See [Communicating With Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html)

(If you're interested in coding your own delegate support, skip down to the "Implementing a Delegate for a Custom Class" section.)

The most significant aspect to take away from delegate methods is that they enable you to customize and affect the behavior of an object without the need to subclass it.

Hope that helps you get started.

Answer (score 2):

If the object(s) in question has its `delegate` assigned to a class you wrote, say a `controller` then the methods defined for being that object's class's `delegate` methods must be implemented by the assigned class. This allows you to effectively control the behavior of the object without sub-classing the object's class in order to override behavior that would likely necessitate an amount of duplicating behavior. It's one of the cleaner parts of the cocoa touch design.

This is something you should pick up in the first couple of intros and tutorials to cocoa touch. Like this [tutorial from Cocoa is my Girlfriend](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/10/01/cocoa-touch-tutorial-iphone-application-example/). In fact they made the `delegate` explanation a big bold heading.