# Creating an object to act as a delegate - Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates

My question is simple actually, how do I create an object to act as a delegate, instead of including the delegate methods in my view?

For example, I have x functionality that requires delegate methods, and they're currently setup to use self as the delegate. I'd like to put those methods in their own object so that the delegate methods can be called and do stuff if the view has ended.

What's the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> for example, NSXMLParser delegate methods - they exist, the delegate is defined, but I dont want to call them as self in my view controller... what other option do I have?

You can specify another custom class to handle the delegate methods, if you wish. Simply create a class, call it `MyXMLParserDelegate` or something similar. Then, all you have to do is tell your `NSXMLParser` object that it should use an instance of your class as its delegate.

If you are using Interface Builder, add a new object to the XIB file, set its class to `MyXMLParserDelegate`, and then drag a connection from your `NSXMLParser` object's `delegate` selector to the new object.

If you are doing it programmatically, the basic operation looks like this:

```
MyXMLParserDelegate * myDelegate = [[MyXMLParserDelegate alloc] init];
[someXMLParser setDelegate:myDelegate];
```

Keep in mind, however, that delegates are not retained, so in order to do this without leaking memory, you should add an ivar of type `MyXMLParserDelegate` to your viewController class, and then do the following:

```
// in your @interface block:
{
    ...
    MyXMLParserDelegate * myDelegate;
}

// in your init method:
myDelegate = [[MyXMLParserDelegate alloc] init];

// in your awakeFromNib method (or anywhere else it seems appropriate):
[someXMLParser setDelegate:myDelegate];

// in your dealloc method:
[myDelegate release];
```

Comment: Hi

Thanks - this does work, and is what I'm doing, so that's good.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this answer, I think it covers what you need: [How to use custom delegates in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645449/how-to-use-custom-delegates-in-objective-c)

Comment: isnt that explaining how to create a delegate? The delegate methods etc are already created as part of the custom class object I am creating. I just dont want to put the delegate methods required in my view controller.

Comment: for example, NSXMLParser delegate methods - they exist, the delegate is defined, but I dont want to call them as self in my view controller... what other option do I have?