# i want to show textfield data in tableviewcell which replace the existance data on cell in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, plist

In my application i hve tableviewcontroller and its detailviewcontroller(dvc). dvc contains textfield and button.I actually want when i clicked on button textfield text is replaced the tableview cell text.what can i do ? explain in detail

Answer (score 0):

1. Define a delegate protocol, that contains the method - (void)textHasChangedTo:(NSString*)text
2. Make tableviewcontroller conforming to this protocol.
3. Implement `- (void)textHasChangedTo:(NSString*)text` on tableviewcontroller, so that it changes the text in the cell. For Example change the text in your model and let the tableView reloadData.
4. Define a delegate property on dvc.
5. Set the delegate of dvc to tableviewcontroller before pushing the dvc onto the navigation stack.
6. In the button action, call textHasChangedTo: on the delegate with the new text.

Comment: hi tonclon
i never ever use of custom protocol so plz more describe becoz i can't get o/p

Comment: take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645449/how-to-use-custom-delegates-in-objective-c

Comment: Hi tonclon how to change the particular cell content from textfield's text becoz i can't set the data what the way to do this plz explain in detail