# Call Function in Underlying ViewController as Modal View Controller is Dismissed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, modalviewcontroller, viewdidappear

I have a mainViewController. I call [self pushModalViewController:someViewController] which makes someViewController the active view.

Now I want to call a function in mainViewController as someViewController disappears with [self dismissModalViewController].

viewDidAppear does not get called probably because the view was already there, just beneath the modal view.   How does one go about calling a function in the mainViewController once the modalView dismisses itself?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

*This answer was rewritten/expanded to explain the 3 most important approaches ([@galambalazs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/378024/galambalazs))*

### 1. Blocks

The simplest approach is using a callback [`block`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html). This is good if you only have **one listener** (the parent view controller) interested in the dismissal. You may even pass some data with the event.

In *MainViewController.m*

```
SecondViewController* svc = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
svc.didDismiss = ^(NSString *data) {
    // this method gets called in MainVC when your SecondVC is dismissed
    NSLog(@"Dismissed SecondViewController");
};
[self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In *SecondViewController.h*

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController
    @property (nonatomic, copy) void (^didDismiss)(NSString *data);
    // ... other properties
@end
```

In *SecondViewController.m*

```
- (IBAction)close:(id)sender 
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    if (self.didDismiss) 
        self.didDismiss(@"some extra data");
}
```

---

### 2. Delegation

[**`Delegation`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH14) is the recommended pattern by Apple:

> **Dismissing a Presented View Controller**
>
> If the presented view controller must return data to the presenting view controller, use the [delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH14) design pattern to facilitate the transfer. Delegation makes it easier to reuse view controllers in different parts of your app. With delegation, the presented view controller stores a reference to a delegate object that implements methods from a formal [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Protocol.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH45). As it gathers results, the presented view controller calls those methods on its delegate. In a typical implementation, the presenting view controller makes itself the delegate of its presented view controller.

**MainViewController**

In *MainViewController.h*

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <SecondViewControllerDelegate>
    - (void)didDismissViewController:(UIViewController*)vc;
    // ... properties
@end
```

Somewhere in *MainViewController.m* (presenting)

```
SecondViewController* svc = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
svc.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Somewhere else in *MainViewController.m* (being told about the dismissal)

```
- (void)didDismissViewController:(UIViewController*)vc
{
    // this method gets called in MainVC when your SecondVC is dismissed
    NSLog(@"Dismissed SecondViewController");
}
```

**SecondViewController**

In *SecondViewController.h*

```
@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)didDismissViewController:(UIViewController*)vc;
@end

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
// ... other properties
@end
```

Somewhere in *SecondViewController.m*

```
[self.delegate myActionFromViewController:self];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

*(note: the protocol with didDismissViewController: method could be reused throughout your app)*

---

### 3. Notifications

Another solution is sending an [**`NSNotification`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/). This is a valid approach as well, it might be easier than delegation in case you only want to *notify* about the dismissal without passing much data. But it's main use case is when you want **multiple listeners** for the dismissal event (other than just the parent view controller).

But make sure to **always** remove yourself from *NSNotificationCentre* after you are done! Otherwise you risk of crashing by being called for notifications even after you are deallocated.  *[editor's note]*

In *MainViewController.m*

```
- (IBAction)showSecondViewController:(id)sender 
{
    SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:secondVC animated:YES completion:nil];

    // Set self to listen for the message "SecondViewControllerDismissed"
    // and run a method when this message is detected
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(didDismissSecondViewController)
     name:@"SecondViewControllerDismissed"
     object:nil];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    // simply unsubscribe from *all* notifications upon being deallocated
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
} 

- (void)didDismissSecondViewController 
{
    // this method gets called in MainVC when your SecondVC is dismissed
    NSLog(@"Dismissed SecondViewController");
}
```

In *SecondViewController.m*

```
- (IBAction)close:(id)sender 
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    // This sends a message through the NSNotificationCenter 
    // to any listeners for "SecondViewControllerDismissed"
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
     postNotificationName:@"SecondViewControllerDismissed" 
     object:nil userInfo:nil];
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: When I change everything to use main delegate: [someViewController setMainDelegate:self];
[self pushModalViewController:someViewController];  [mainDelegate someActionFromViewController:self];
[self dismissModalViewController];  ...... it will build but crash   Are you sure this syntax works?  Do I need to declare the delegate?

Comment: Sorry, yes you will have to declare the delegate in your @interface section.  I also suggest creating a protocol to make sure you calling an object that can handle the message you are sending.  So id<MyDelegate> delegate;

Comment: I used this link to create the protocol and declaration.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645449/how-to-use-custom-delegates-in-objective-c

Comment: @protocol PropertiesControllerDelegate <NSObject> -- id<PropertiesControllerDelegate> delegate; --  But I am still getting a crash at the setDelegate method.....-[PropertiesController setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x177840
2010-11-10 19:27:29.463 iScoutShoes[4142:307] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PropertiesController setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x177840'

Comment: Do I need to add the protocol in the mainViewController class too? I can't seem to figure this out. Thanks so much for all of your help already.

Comment: So, the link you provided looked pretty good.  Notice that they have an `@property` declaration and presumably a `@synthesize` as well.  You will have to do that in your PropertiesController class.  The @property/@synthesize pair will make a getter and setter for your `id<PropertiesControllerDelegate> delegate;` field inside of your PropertiesController.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Edited answer to hopefully illustrate better.  Hope that's a little better.

Comment: Where can I find a Swift version of that?

Answer (score 7):

### Using exit (unwind) segue

When you're using storyboards and segues you can use a very handy approach with minimal code to dismiss a modal view controller and inform the underlying view controller that the modal view controller has been closed.

Using exit (unwind) segues you gain 3 advantages:

1. **you don't need to write any code** to dismiss the modal view controller and
2. you can have iOS call a **callback method inside the underlying view controller** that has presented the model view controller.
3. you use the very same semantics that you already know from implementing `prepareForSegue:`

### Implement it with only 2 steps

1. Create an action method in the **Parent** view controller that presents another (modal) view controller:

**Swift**

```
@IBAction func unwindFromSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    print("Unwind from segue", segue.identifier)
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
- (IBAction)unwindFromSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    NSLog(@"Unwind from segue %s", segue.identifier);
}
```

2. In the storyboard, On **child view controller** right click the *exit segue* (aka unwind segue, it's the last of the icons at the top of your view controller), drag & drop `unwindFromSegue:` to your button and select *action*.

[image]

You're done! Now the modal view controller closes when you click the `dismiss` button and `unwindFromSegue:` informs your underlying view controller(**Parent**) that the modal view controller(**Child**) has closed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a callback solution which takes less modifications to your modal and parent:
In the Model's .h add:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^dismissed)();
```

In the Model's .m put this in the completion when you dismiss the modal:

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    if(self.dismissed)
        self.dismissed();
}];
```

In the parent view controller when you instantiate your modal set the dismissed callback:

```
Modal = //Init your modal
[Modal setDismissed:^{
   //do stuff you wanted when it's dimissed
}];
 [self presentViewController:Modal animated:YES completion:nil];
```