# Send the value in Class of ViewController to Class of View

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any way that could send the value in Class of ViewController to Class of View?
Because I want to make a drawing board and I made a modal scene to set values about color, width . 
I know how to send the value in modal scene to my ViewController , but now I need use those value in Class of View , or not Class of ViewController.

Comment: I have my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25616250/refreshing-parent-viewcontroller-after-dismissing-modalviewcontroller/25617263#25617263

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to devise a [*protocol*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html) to open a [*delegation*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html) channel between the two classes. Then when the modal VC wants to send data to its delegate (its presenter, in this case), it can of its own volition.

Answer (score 0):

The View Controller can have a reference to the View, therefore the View Controller can simply pass the values to View by calling a View's method or updating View's properties. This is a common pattern: View defines a Protocol and data/requests from View to ViewController go through this Protocol (the ViewController acts as delegate of View); and ViewController owns the View.

For inspiration on how to implement a farily decoupled design applying this pattern, you can have a look at documentation on `UICollectionView` and `UICollectionViewController`.

Other options, depending on what design you need, are Key-Value Observing or Notifications.