# How to pass text field's text from one view controller to other view controller using custom delegate

Tags: delegates

I have created text field,label and button in one two view controllers.My scenario is after entering the text in first view controller if i press th e button, the text field's text should display in label of next view controller.Again if i press the button in second view controller after entering the text it should display in first view controller's label.I want the solution by using custom delegates.Thanks in advance

Comment: i can give you solution using NSNotification object, when the second view controller, get dismissed, the value from it will come to first view controller.

Comment: if you still want to use delegate,
use this url
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203799/dismissmodalviewcontroller-and-pass-data-back

Comment: if you want to use the notification method, use this URL
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387039/how-can-i-detect-the-dismissal-of-a-modal-view-controller-in-the-parent-view-con