# Transparent View Controller Background When Presented Full Screen

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I present a view controller(B) over another(A) where I want the background of B to be transparent so that A is still visible in the background.

Therefore, before presenting B, it's `modalPresentationStyle` is set to be `.overCurrentContext` and B has `view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear` so that the transparent background is present.

However when I dismiss B and return back to A, methods of A like `viewDidAppear`, `viewWillAppear`, etc. does not get re-triggered.

If I change the above `modalPresentationStyle` to `.fullScreen`, `viewWillAppear` and such will get re-triggered when returned back to A but this time, I lose the transparent background.

All in all, how can I achieve both a transparent background on the presented view and re-trigger methods such as `viewDidAppear` on A when I return back to A?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you present full screen the presenting view is removed from view - so there is nothing to see through your transparent view. So this method will not work for you.

When you present over the current context the presenting view remains - but that is **why** viewDidAppear etc do not get called - it never went away so it has not re-appeared.

Instead of viewDidAppear use another method of detecting that your transparent view has been dismissed, such as an unwind segue or one of the other methods discussed in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4150677/2466193).