# Run a method after subclass of UIAlertView gets dismissed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, delegates, uialertview

I create custom login page by using UIAlerView subclass. Now when i click on button it opens up UIAlertView I want to change the main view based on which button is pressed.

But as all implementation of UIAlerView is in another class though i change the view it doesn't retain that as that class variable doesn't get it's value.

Can anyone please help me with this? I can post the code if required.

Thank you,
Ankita

Comment: you need to use delegate methods to communicate between the two classes.

Comment: @Robin: Can you tell me how to use delegate methods between two classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom init method like below for alertView and store the _sender in global or class variable. like

```
id sender;
- (id)initWithSender:(id)_sender
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        sender=_sender;
    }
    return self;
}
```

from RootVC/bgview initialize alertView as follows and define a method named

```
-(void) alertIndexSelected:(NSInterger) index;
```

{

//change the backgound view based on button selected
}
 in rootvc/your main view.

```
  alertViewobj =[[alertView alloc] initWithSender:self];
```

when the button is selected on alertview call the below method, this will notify your rootvc about which index of alert is pressed. use following alertview delegate.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
[sender alertIndexSelected: buttonIndex];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to use delegate methods then I think you need to referrer to some of these links.

[How to use custom delegates in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645449/how-to-use-custom-delegates-in-objective-c)

[How do I create delegates in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c)

http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html

I hope this will help you a great deal in understanding delegates.