# What is the meaning of "id<I> i" in Objective-C programming?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

```
@protocol I <NSObject>
-(void) f;
-(void) g;
@end

@interface C : NSObject <I> 
{
    id<I> i;
}
-(void) toA;
-(void) toB;
@end
```

I am using this code, Here I am using a protocol I, I want to know what is the meaning of
 ( id< I > i ) and working of this.

Comment: Are you really using __this__ code? I mean, calling your objects A, B, f, g, i?

Comment: This is a sample to know the working of the @protocol and if i am taking A, B, f, g and i so what's wrong in this i am felling comfortable with these name

Comment: Why not writing your code already minified, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaration:

```
MyClass<MyProtocol> * myVar;
```

means that class of myVar is one of MyClass descendants and additionaly implements methods of MyProtocol protocol.
Read more about protocols [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html).

And in your code

```
id<I> i;
```

means that "i" is of id type - i.e. it can  be object of any class (read  about id [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW3)),
but is also conforms to protocol  "I".

In you sample class of your "i" must implement

```
-(void) f;
-(void) g;
```

methods.

And you can use expressions like:

```
[i f];
[i g];
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that the iVar  `i` of *any* type (thus `id`), conforms to protocol `I`.

Comment: Here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html

Answer (score 0):

You declared `i` as an Objective-C object of type id that conforms to your protocol `I`.

Read more about it here: http://unixjunkie.blogspot.com/2008/03/id-vs-nsobject-vs-id.html

Answer (score 0):

i is an object. It could be any class, as long as that class conforms to the protocol I. That means that class has instance methods f and g that take no arguments and return nothing. That class also must formally adopt protocol I. Class C actually adopts protocol I. Inside a method of class C you could write:

```
i = self;
```

Though that might not usually be very useful. More likely some other class adopts protocol I too, or at least you would assign a different instance of C to i, like

```
i = [[C alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

id refers to a variable that adheres to the protocol I.  In this case, you would then need i to be be a variable whose class implements protocol I.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to read up on the delegates here: [How to use custom delegates in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645449/how-to-use-custom-delegates-in-objective-c)

The id i is your delegate property. When you use it. You can call one of the delegate methods you described in your protocol, aka method f and g. In the class that comforms to the protocol you given shape to these methods.