# After removal of a overlay view which method get called

Tags: iphone

i have a small doubt that how to call a method form one class to other class ,and this method is define in called class .

i wants to use the Protocol class but i don't know how to use this .
 so can any one can help me to use the protocol class,with a example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Need to create delegate for the same, You can check many questions are available for the same.

[How to use custom delegates in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645449/how-to-use-custom-delegates-in-objective-c)

Comment: yes,i found the this related question.