# Loading an action in firstViewController declared in secondViewController

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios6

I am still new to iOS programming (and programming at all) and trying to figure out some basics. My question is:

I want to click a button in secondViewController to show the text "The Button in secondViewController was pressed" in firstViewController - is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.... There can be various ways to do it....
You can try these solutions:
1. Delegates
2. Local Notifications
3. KVO
4. Using shared instances(like AppDelegate)

There are various resources available on the internet for all of these... I need not mention them in detail.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please link to an example or link where I can find some details?

Comment: Try to go through delegates... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645449/how-to-use-custom-delegates-in-objective-c