# Is there a way to distinguish between which UIPopOver is dismissed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

I have several popovers in my application and I am having difficulty in determining which popover was dismissed. Is there a "tag" feature equivalent for UIPopOvers?

I can `NSLog` the popoverController in the popoverContorllerDidDismissPopover method and see the memory reference of each one but that doesn't help.

```
#pragma mark - Popover controller delegates
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
    NSLog(@"Popover dismised %@", popoverController);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could use `UIPopOverController` with blocks? This way you wouldn't have to care about that.

Comment: What are you trying to acheive?

Comment: My goal is that when a specific popover is dismissed, I can update a couple of different button states. But not until after the popover is dismissed. Yes, I could continuously up date the buttons state based up whatever is changed, but that isn't my requirement.

Comment: I think in that case you might want to look into using a delegate.

Answer (score 1):

An extract from [here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/305826-dismissing-popover-internally.html):

> If I understand the question, then basically, no - and it's maddening.
>   On the one hand you're told that only one popover should be showing at
>   any one moment. On the other hand you don't automatically get a
>   reference to that popover. Thus it is up to you to store a reference,
>   manually, to the current popover controller at the time it shows its
>   popover, so that you can talk to it later in order to dismiss it.
>   Popover controller management can thus get really elaborate and
>   clumsy; you're doing all kinds of work that the system should just be
>   doing for you.
>
> iOS is funny this way. I'm reminded of how there's no call in iOS 4
>   that tells you current first responder. Obviously the system knows
>   what the first responder is, so why won't it tell you? It's kind of
>   dumb. This is similar; the system clearly knows useful stuff it won't
>   share with you. m.

Comment: As per HIG only one popover should be displayed...rest you have guessed.

Comment: I really don't understand the the problem with holding a reference to the popover that has been presented.  For every popover you have just store a reference and check the reference in the DidDismiss. Am I missing something more from the question?

Comment: @John You are absolutely right. However, introducing a new state variable is not always the best solution. In a complicated iPad application you can have many different popovers shown from the same screen and if you handle them all in one delegate method, you end up having a big `switch` or `if-else` comparing the popover type. It's better to remove the `switch` and move to dismiss handler closer to the code  creating the popover, e.g. using blocks (check my answer).

Answer (score 0):

As @Anoop stated, you can usually only have one popover showing at a time.

One possible solution is to check the `contentViewController` property on the pop over. If you are storing a reference of each view controller you could do something like:

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
    if ( popoverController.contentViewController == self.someUIViewController ) {
        // do stuff
    }
    else if ( popoverController.contentViewController == someoTherViewController ) {
       //
    }
    NSLog(@"Popover dismised %@", popoverController);
}
```

If storing a reference to each content view controller is not possible (or maybe just not a good idea), you could always check its type:

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
    if ( [popoverController.contentViewController isKindOfClass:[MyAwesomeViewController class]] ) {
        // do stuff
    }
    else if ( [popoverController.contentViewController isKindOfClass:[MyOtherViewController class]] ) {
        //
    }
    NSLog(@"Popover dismised %@", popoverController);
}
```

Another possible solution, which is probably better from a design stand point of view, would be to pass in a delegate to the view controller contained in the pop over. [More here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1218098/620197). This way, the view controller displayed can send data back to your main view controller.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways how to distinguish between popovers. I will list few of them:

1. You are asking about `tag`. Note that every popover has a content view controller and this controller has a view that can be tagged. However, using magic integer tags to distinguish between views is arguable in general.
2. Store the type of the popover into a variable/property in your controller, e.g. as an `enum`. This is the simplest way.
3. Add the neccessary information to the popover, but be clever about it, e.g.

```
@interface MyPopoverController : UIPopoverController 

@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) void (^dissmissHandler)(void);

@end

@implementation MyPopoverController 

- (id)initWithContentViewController:(UIViewController*)contentView {
   self = [super initWithContentViewController:contentView];

   if (!self) {
      return nil;
   }

   self.delegate = self;

   return self;
}

- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController*)popover {
    assert(popover == self);

    if (self.dissmissHandler) {
       self.dissmissHandler();
    }
}

@end
```

`MyPopoverController* popover = [MyPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:...];
popover.dissmissHandler = ^{
   ...
};`

Comment: (add `autorelease` and `dealloc` for MRC)

Comment: Blocks are still a very abstract concept to me.

Comment: @JasonBourne Okey, but you will have to understand them sooner or later. It's not the only option I have listed.