# Get download progress from different ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, afnetworking

I have a `VideoListController`. It has list of videos with download button. When I press the download button, the control is transferred to `DetailViewController`. In `DetailViewController`, I am using `AFNetworking` to download file.

If I go back to `VideoListController` from `DetailViewController`. How can I know progress of download or when download gets completed from `VideoListController`. I want to know this because based upon that I will reload the list to show play button instead of download.

Comment: i got ur point for download complete thing, but could u tell me, how r u updating download progress values in other view controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working using NSNotificationCenter.
In viewDidLoad of DetailViewController, I added this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(movieDownloadDidFinish)
                                             name:@"MovieDownloadDidFinishNotification"
                                           object:nil];
```

When download gets complete. I call this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MovieDownloadDidFinishNotification" object:self];
```

I remove the observer from DetailViewController when when backbutton in navigation controller is clicked

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"MovieDownloadDidFinishNotification" object:nil];
```

And added method in DetailViewController that is called when download gets completed.

```
-(void) movieDownloadDidFinish {
    NSLog(@"MovieDownloadDidFinish on DetailViewController");
}
```

Now in viewDidAppear of VideoListController, I added the observer

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(movieDownloadDidFinish)
                                             name:@"MovieDownloadDidFinishNotification"
                                           object:nil];
```

And in viewDidDisappear Of VideoListController, I remove the observer

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"MovieDownloadDidFinishNotification" object:nil];
```

And added method in VideoListController that is called when download gets completed.

```
-(void) movieDownloadDidFinish {
    NSLog(@"MovieDownloadDidFinish On VideoListController");
}
```

In this way, when DetailViewController is visible, the method movieDownloadDidFinish of DetailViewController is called and similarly movieDownloadDidFinish of VideoListController is called when VideoListController is visible.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best solution for your problem would be to create a custom `delegate` protocol that the `DetailViewController` and the `VideoListController` can use to communicate with each other. Check this post for additional information [How to use custom delegates in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645449/how-to-use-custom-delegates-in-objective-c)

In a nutshell the strategy is the following:
 1. The `DetailViewController` defines a `delegate` `protocol` that it uses to pass events to its delegate 
 2. The `VideoListController` becomes the delegate to that it knows whenever an upload has progressed or been completed
 3. The `VideoListController` keeps track of which `DetailViewController`s have completed the download

Here is come code:
`DetailViewController.h`:

```
@class DetailViewController;
@protocol Delegate <NSObject>
- (void) detailViewController: (DetailViewController *) theDetailViewController didFinishDownloadingVideoWithResults:(BOOL)successful;
@end

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<DetailViewController> delegate;
```

`DetailViewController.m`:
Whenever a download is complete do the following:

```
if ([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(detailViewController:didFinishDownloadingVideoWithResults:)]){
   [[self delegate] detailViewController:self didFinishDownloadingVideoWithResults:YES];
}
```

Now, in the `VideoListController.m` make sure you establish yourself as the delegate of the `DetailViewController`.

```
[theDetailViewController setDelegate:self];
```

And implement the delegate method. You can for instance have a dictionary that defines which DetailViewControllers have completed the download:

```
   - (void) detailViewController: (DetailViewController *) theDetailViewController didFinishDownloadingVideoWithResults:(BOOL)successful{
      detailViewControllersDownloadInformation[theDetailViewController] = @(successful);
}
```

Now, whenever you need to check if a `DetailViewController` did indeed complete a download, all you have to do is check that dictionary

```
if (detailViewControllersDownloadInformation[theDetailViewController] && detailViewControllersDownloadInformation[theDetailViewController] == @(YES)){
    // Did download a video
}
```

Keep in mind that the solution I provide will only let you know if the download has been completed. If you also want to keep track of the progress you need to pass that as an additional parameter in the delegate. We are also assuming that you keep all of the `DetailViewController`s in memory. If you release and reuse them you will need to keep track of which element was downloaded in a different data structure.

Comment: I am getting error here: @property (nonatomic, weak) id<DetailViewController> delegate;

I think it should be id<Delegate> delegate;
Is it?

Comment: I have implemented It like this:
@ class DetailViewController;
@ protocol Delegate <NSObject>
- (void) detailViewController: (DetailViewController *) theDetailViewController didFinishDownloadingVideoWithResults:(BOOL)successful;
@ end

@ property (nonatomic, weak) id<Delegate> delegate;

@end

Comment: In DetailViewController, when the download gets completed. I add this:
                if ([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(detailViewController:didFinishDownloadingVideoWithResults:)]){
                    [[self delegate] detailViewController:self detailViewController:didFinishDownloadingVideoWithResults:YES];
                }
But i get this error: Use of undeclared identifier 'didFinishDownloadingVideoWithResults'

Comment: There was a typo, try it now using: [[self delegate] detailViewController:self didFinishDownloadingVideoWithResults:YES];

Comment: Since I was getting warning, In VideoListController, I added delegate like this: @interface RowViewController : UITableViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate, Delegate>

When I come back from DetailViewController to VideoListController, while downloading, still this method does not get called.
-(void) detailViewController:(DetailViewController *)theDetailViewController didFinishDownloadingVideoWithResults:(BOOL)successful {
    NSLog(@"Download Completed!");
}