# Track download progress from various ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, viewcontroller

I have an app. 
It has `VideoListViewController` that has list of videos to download. 
When I click the download button, the control is transferred to `DetailViewController`. 
`DetailViewController` shows the download progress and when download gets completed, it plays the video. After download gets completed I changed `isDownloaded` to `true`, so that next time it shows play button instead of download.

Everything works perfectly if the user don't go to previous `VideoListViewController` while video is being downloaded. If it does go back to VideoListController, then I don't know the progress of download, neither when the download gets completed. Since from VideoListController I don't know when the download gets completed, I can't change the download button to play when the download gets completed.

Please help me to know how can one keep track of download progress and download completion event from various controllers or atleast from two different controller.

Do I need to keep the downloading function in `AppDelegate`. Please elaborate in detail. I am new to iOS

Comment: you also accept this answer..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251054/get-download-progress-from-different-viewcontroller

Comment: I unaccepted it. It didn't work. Although I up voted him for his effort.

Comment: What part didn't work in the `delegate` solution? That seems like a perfectly good answer to me..

Comment: @Mar0ux I have added my comments there. Please have a look at them.

Comment: Check the last comment there :) (and please remove this question if your query has been resolved by the last one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Tasks like that Apple introduced the NSNotificationcenter.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

With this you can make a thread notify different classes when it finished it's execution.

Comment: I have described the implementation here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251054/get-download-progress-from-different-viewcontroller