# Updating uilabel in view controller underneath another

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uilabel

I have two view controllers, FirstViewController and FourthViewController. FirstViewController is my initial view controller. I present FourthViewController with

```
UIViewController *fourthController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithID:@"Fourth"];
[self presentViewController:fourthController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Then, in FourthViewController's .m I'd like to change the text of a UILabel in FirstViewController. So I use

```
UIViewController *firstController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithID:@"First"];
firstController.mainLab.text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"New Text"];
```

However, after I use

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

I find that my mainLab's text has not updated. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3):

When you are calling this line from FourthViewController.m you are actually creating a new instance of FirstViewController, rather than using the already created one.

```
UIViewController *firstController = [self.storyboard 
                             instantiateViewControllerWithID:@"First"];
```

You can tackle this in two ways.

### 1) Using notification

post a notification from FourthViewController when label text need to be changed.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateLabel" 
        object:self];
```

In your FirstViewController `viewDidLoad` methodcreate an observer that waits for this notification to get fired.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(updateLabelCalled:) 
        name:@"updateLabel"
        object:nil];
```

Implement `updateLabelCalled:` and update label.

```
- (void) updateLabelCalled:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"updateLabel"]){
        //write code to update label
    }

}
```

### 2) Implementing delegate

It is already explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645449/how-to-use-custom-delegates-in-objective-c) in stackoverflow. The basic idea is you create a FourthViewController delegate, and create a delegate method to updateLabel. FirstViewController should implement this method.

Comment: What if I defined firstController in the interface of FirstViewController? Would I still be creating a new instance of FirstViewController?

Comment: @user1626438 I am not sure I understand your question

Comment: In FirstViewController's interface, if I defined: FirstViewController *firstController;

Comment: @user1626438 Oh I got it, but I wouldn't do that if I were you. The notification thing is pretty easy. That is the best and easier way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the label on first screen and nothing else then go for notifications. It's better rather you write the delegate. Because you want to update only label text thats it.