# Access Method from another controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a button action function in a controller named as "Remotecontroller". this is the method:

```
-(IBAction)startDiscover:(id)sender{.....}
```

I have another controller named as "iptvViewcontroller". I need to call the above method in this "iptvViewcontroller" when a button click. this is my button click function:

```
btnRefresh3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            btnRefresh3.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 20);
            [btnRefresh3 addTarget:self action:@selector(startDiscover:) 
            [arrLeftBarItems addObject:barButtonItem3];
```

Please somebody help me to make it work.

Comment: You can easily do this if you can find the reference of `RemoteController` if it exists in memory and assign instead of `self in addTarget`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Remotecontroller.m`, set NotificationCenter like this in your `viewDidLoad` :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(startDiscover) name:@"discover" object:nil];
```

In Remotecontroller.m

```
-(void)startDiscover
{
    /////Your Code
}
```

In iptvViewcontroller.m

```
[btnRefresh3 addTarget:self action:@selector(startDiscoverFromRemoteController);


-(void)startDiscoverFromRemoteController
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"discover" object:nil];
}
```

Comment: This is a correct approach. Another way you can achieve this is to create a custom protocol delegate.

Answer (score 1):

By creating and using custom delegate , you can achieve that functionality.

An Objective-C delegate is an object that has been assigned to the delegate property another object.

See below links for details and How to create and use custom delegate.

1.[How do I create delegates in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c)

2.[How to use custom delegates in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645449/how-to-use-custom-delegates-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

To call one method to another class you have to write your method in Remotecontroller.h file

```
-(IBAction)startDiscover:(id)sender;
```

then your remotecontroller class import in iptvViewcontroller class in .h file like this

```
#import "Remotecontroller.h"
```

now to use that method you have to create and alloc init object of remotecontroller class in iptvViewcontroller class in iptvViewcontroller.h file `viewdidload()` method

```
Remotecontroller *remote;
```

in iptvViewcontroller.m file

```
remote = [Remotecontroller alloc]init];
```

now you can use your method throughout the class

```
[remote startDiscover:parameter];
```